# Multiple get requests to Github API

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am trying to make multiple get requests to the GitHub API to retrieve some data. I desire to use express to render the information. There will be multiple requests and I was wondering how I should structure and design this. For example a single request looks like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, options) {
  request({ url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/somename/someproject',json: true, headers: {'user-Agent': 'request'}}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body.language);
  });
});
```

If I wanted to make many requests to different URLs, it would look like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, options) {
  request({ url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/somename/someproject',json: true, headers: {'user-Agent': 'request'}}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body.language);
  });
  request({ url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/anothername/anotherproject',json: true, headers: {'user-Agent': 'request'}}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
  });
});
```

I am new to javascript. Is there a neater way to do write this? I am also looking to render this information to a view file later which I know I can do by `res.render`

EDIT:

This works:

```
 var option1 = {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/somename/someproject',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        json: true
      };

    var option2 = {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/somename/someproject',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        json: true
      };

      function getRequest(option1) {
        return new Promise(function (success, failure) {
            request(option1, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    success(console.log(body));
                } else {
                    failure(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    getRequest(option1).then(function (body1) {
        console.log(body1)
        return getRequest(option2);
    }).then(function (body2) {
        console.log(body2);
    });
```

Comment: its time to use promise in your code

Comment: That's how you do it

Comment: Could you write an example so the question can be answered please?

Comment: Could someone have a look at my edited code. Is this a bad way of doing it?